# cannot find crt1.o and crti.o

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying compiling a code and I'm stuck on the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I added a path to my environmental variables with location of booth art?.o files and I created a symbolic link. Error persists.
I have also installed gcc-multilib and libc6-i386, and the error goes on.
Anyone have an ideia of what is going on? How to fix? Any help are welcome.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"trying compiling a code"*? what command(s) are you using? what is your Ubuntu version and machine architecture?

Comment: Install `build-essential` : You seem to be missing one or more "essential" → I.e. `libc6-dev` provides `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/{crt1.o, crti.o}` etc. etc. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libc6-dev/filelist

Comment: System is Lubuntu 18.04. I run a script  with all different programs needed to compiling the code. 
crti.o and crt1.o are inside  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  nevertheless,  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory doesn't see those files, even with symbolic link.

Comment: The point is that code I’m trying to compile doesn’t need crti.o and crt1.o

Comment: I ran into the same problem with Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS.  I installed libc6 and libc6-dev both.  However, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory still does not include {crt1.o, crti.o}.  There must be another package that will install those, but I cannot figure out what that is.  (By the way build-essential package is installed.)